# How to prove that this function is increasing?

Tags: calculus, functions

$(a^x-1)/(x)$ is growing?, For $a>1, x>0$
I would like to know some way to prove that this function is increasing, without using derivation techniques, only with the basic calculation, using limits if necessary.

Comment: In shortcut,take an arbitrary value of $a$.say,$a=5$,now,put x1=2 and calculate y1,then put x2=3 and calculate y2,as we are seeing clearly x2>x1,so if y2>y1,then the function is increasing....

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince How is a single example a valid "shortcut" to a proof?

Comment: I haven't titled it as a proof ,sir.I have just shown it as a way to see the function is increasing.

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince But that is not a way to see that the function is increasing.  At best, you see something which is consistent with the claim being true, but which is also consistent with the claim being false.

Comment: Sir, it is basically working as a power function,as $x$ is increasing and $x>0$ the function gets higher and higher more.It is also visible from it's graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly Increasing function for $f(x)$means $$\forall x_1,x_2$$ $$x_1 > x_2 => f(x_1) > f(x_2)$$
In your case, let $$f(x) = \frac{a^x - 1}{x} = t, f(x_1) = t_1, f(x_2) = t_2$$
Now,
$$a^x = xt + 1$$
$$=>x\ln{a} = \ln{(xt + 1)}$$
So,
$$x_1 > x_2$$
$$=>x_1\ln{a} > x_2\ln{a}$$
$$=>x_1\ln{a} > \ln(x_2t_2 + 1)$$
$$=>\ln(x_1t_1 + 1) > \ln(x_2t_2 + 1)$$
$$=>x_1t_1 + 1 > x_2t_2 + 1$$
$$=>x_1t_1 > x_2t_2$$.
$$=>(x_2+c)t_1 > x_2t_2$$, where $x_1 = x_2 + c, c > 0$
$$=>(x_2t_1 + ct_1) > x_2t_2$$
$$=>(x_2t_1 - x_2t_2) + ct_1) > 0$$
$$=>(x_2(t_1 - t_2) + ct_1) > 0$$
Now we know that $c > 0, t_1 = \frac{a^{x_1} - 1}{x_1} > 0$ because $a > 1, x >0$
so, $ct_1 > 0$
$$=>x_2(t_1 - t_2) > 0$$
Since $x_2 > 0 =>(t_1 - t_2) > 0 =>t_1 > t_2$,

So $f(x)$ is Strictly Increasing

Comment: I'm not sure about the last inequality $t_1>t_2$. Counter-example: $x_1=3, t_1=4, x_2=2, t_2=5$. Then $x_1 t_1=3\times4>2\times5=x_2 t_2$ and $x_1=3>2=x_2$ but it does not follow that $t_1=4>5=t_2$.

Comment: $t_1$ in this case cannot be 4 since it is $\frac{a^3 -1}{3}$. it depends on $a$. Note that $t_1 = f(x_1)$

Comment: The point is that $t_1>t_2$ does not follow from $x_1 t_1 > x_2 t_2 \wedge x_1>x_2$. Your argument assumes this to always be the case.

Comment: $x_2(t_1-t_2)>0$ still does not follow.

Comment: Thanks! Yes. I see your point. Let me see if I can find an easier proof.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use the Maclaurin series for $\exp(x)$ then

$$a^x = \exp(x\ln a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x\ln a)^n}{n!} = 1 + x\ln a + \frac{(x\ln a)^2}{2!} + \cdots$$

so

$$\frac{a^x-1}{x} = \ln a + \frac{(\ln a)^2}{2!}x + \frac{(\ln a)^3}{3!}x^2 + \cdots$$

Each non-constant term in this series is an increasing function of $x$ for $x>0$, so the entire function is too.